# VS Code takes several seconds to save a document in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

This is my C/C++ configs in `/home/user/.config/Code/User/settings.json`:

```json
  "C_Cpp.formatting": "clangFormat",
  "C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
  "C_Cpp.dimInactiveRegions": false,
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_path": "/usr/bin/clang-format",
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_sortIncludes": true,
  "C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.enabled": true,
  "C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.path": "/usr/bin/clang-tidy",
  "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++23",
  "C_Cpp.default.cStandard": "c17",
  "C_Cpp.autocompleteAddParentheses": true,
  "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang"
```

Now when i try to save a C++ document, sometimes it takes several seconds to save and sometimes not:

[image]

However when i try developing in Rust, this problem does not exist:

[image]

How can i fix that problem as it is so annoying?

Also is there a way to see what's happening while saving in vs code so that i can know what is the process that causes this delay?

Comment: You must have an extension that causes this. try disabling them one by one.

Comment: I have disabled all the extentions in my vscode and still the problem persists. I have disabled them one by one as you suggested until i turned them all off. I think if the problem was from one of the extentions of vs code, then it will also occur while developing in Rust. Maybe it's something is clang-format

Comment: Are you saving to a network drive or shared folder?  That can slow things down.

Comment: That problem was due to an unresponsive extension which was git. So i updated it and now everything is fine. It is weird tho that the git extension is responsive and works fine with Rust.

Comment: Refer to the latest update in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vscode, i tried to disable all the extensions that i installed previously, i disabled them one by one, after each disable, i test by changing the code then saving, yet the problem persists, until all the extensions are off.

Then i remembered there are some other built-in extensions. I opened the extensions, then pressed on the three dots at the top right of the left side bar, then i chose `Show running extensions`, the `Running extensions` will open and you will find among them git. I noticed that git in unresponsive and had a huge number beside it like `4000+ms` which is substantially greater than all the other extensions.

Notice that i am using git version `2.34.1`. Also the git extension is ok and responsive during Rust development.

So i updated git to the latest version which is `2.37.1` using these commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install git`

Now i restarted vscode and the git extension is responsive and working properly. Also the saving is fast and everything in fine.

The problem was due to unresponsive git extension only in C++ development as far as i know. So update git to the latest version.

**Update:**

I think the problem still exists even after i updated git to the latest version. The delay still only happens with C++ development. The problem is solved once i initialized git in my working directory using `git init`. When i restart vscode, everything works fine. Here is a screenshot of the Running extensions when the problem exists (Notice the first git extension):
[image]

**Update:**

I think i knew where the problem is. The directory of my C++ project is  `/home/user/Projects/cpp/testing_1`, in `cpp/` directory i put all my C++ projects such as `testing_1/`, `testing_2/` and so on. I initialized git in `cpp/` dir before which is the parent dir of all my projects. When i deleted that `.git` dir in `cpp/` the git extension in responsive and working fine, even when i am not initializing git in my working project such as `testing_1/`. I think not initializing git in the parent dir of your project solved the problem. I will see where that goes.